# An embeddable web server with native @WebService support as an alternative to Endpoint.publish

Tags: java, web-services, endpoint

I have spent some time on investigating what Endpoint.publish can and cannot do, and it appears that you very quickly enter undocumented territory.

In case you build a simple stand alone application which expose one or more @WebService annotated classes with Endpoint.publish and you then run into a situation where you cannot use Endpoint.publish any more (for any reason) what is then the simplest migration path?

I know that you can create a WAR with sun-jaxws.xml and optionally Metro jars which you can then deploy to an embedded web server (like Jetty or Winstone) but I like the simple "take THIS class and expose it at THIS url" API of Endpoint.publish() without any XML or full containers.

Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: Please help me understand your requirement. Are you looking for some solution which will let you use `Endpoint.publish() ` (_and not any alternatives_) and still helps you get around the issues you are facing (_like using https etc_) OR some completely different way but as simple as `Endpoint.publish() ` ?

Comment: Yes, I want a solution which does _not_ use `Endpoint` in any way.

Answer (score 0):

[It's been said](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/jitu/archive/2006/07/how_to_use_endp.html) that you can an instance of [`com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html) to customize the HTTP behavior of the endpoint. It's always a good idea to be cautious of `com.sun` APIs but it might be appropriate depending your situation. There's an [HttpsServer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpsServer.html) subclass that can be used to provide SSL, for example.

The process seems to be:

1. Use [`HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(listenPortNumber), waitQueueDepth)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html#create%28java.net.InetSocketAddress,%20int%29) to create a server instance.
2. Use [`server.createContext("/path")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html#createContext%28java.lang.String%29) to create a context that will host the endpoint.
3. Create an endpoint with `Endpoint.create(new RpcLitEndpoint())`. It's not clear where `RpcLitEndpoint` is defined or whether it's strictly required; it may be part of Metro JAX-WS.
4. Call `endpoint.publish(context)` to associate the endpoint with the `HttpServer` (or `HttpsServer`) instance.

When done, use `endpoint.stop` and `server.stop` to shut down.

There's also a [blog entry on blogs.oracle.com](https://blogs.oracle.com/oleksiys/entry/how_to_create_custom_network) describing the creation of custom network transports. It didn't have enough detail for me to get a great understanding from a quick scan, but maybe you can get more out of it.

Comment: This is still using `Endpoint`.  I am looking for an alternative.

Comment: I explicitly asked for a way to avoid Endpoint.publish to have an alternative.  Your answer explicitly mentions Endpoint.publish in point 4.

Comment: Yes it does. But why is avoiding Endpoint.publish a requirement? Why not avoid something equally useful, like Java generics? I'm trying to better understand the requirements. What's wrong with Endpoint.publish if it otherwise meets your needs?

Comment: Please reread the question - the question is about a migration path when `Endpoint` _for any reason_ is not usable any more and you need a replacement.  Our deployment JVM is a non-Oracle JVM on a proprietary platform, so I am _very_ weary on relying on any internal Sun classes.  Answering "Just use Endpoint anyway" is not exactly suggesting an alternative which is what I asked for.

Comment: The point is that unless you have some reasonable suggestions about where the existing solution might fall short, it's darned difficult to imagine general solutions that won't have the same potential shortcomings.

Comment: I _have_ reviewed your responses - saying "Use Endpoint anyway" is simply not answering my question.  Please point out to me how I can use _anything_ in your answer in the context of my question.  Also the google search link you gave is unfortunately not relevant to this at all.

Comment: No, the _premise_ of the question is that in a given situation Endpoint.publish() will suddenly not meet my needs.  The actual cause might be something completely different - time will show.    Is this clear enough for you to understand now?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're still poking at my response. It's clear that you're looking for a solution to a poorly-defined problem. You could as easily (and uselessly) ask, "What if Java bytecode stopped meeting my needs?" Consider this -- what if I said, "look at the JDK source code and write a class that does exactly what Endpoint does, adjusting as necessary to meet your new requirements"? It would fit the requirements. But it's a useless answer.

Comment: The deleted comment looked like a question.  My bad.